# Stationary curves on homogeneous spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

Consider $M \cong G/K$ ($G$ a lie group with a transitive action on $M$ and $K$ a subgroup) and consider a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}: TM \rightarrow \ \mathbb{R}$ (no time dependence). Consider also that $\mathcal{L}$ is also homogeneous order one in tangent vectors i.e. $\mathcal{L}(p, \lambda x ) = \lambda \mathcal{L}(p, x)$ so that actions assigned to curves are independent of parametrization.

When exactly are the stationary curves $\gamma(t)$ of $\mathcal{L}$ on $M$ of the form $e^{tA} \circ \gamma_0$ where $\gamma_0$ is one of the end points of the curve and $\circ$ is the action of $G$ on $M$.

Comment: Are you assuming any invariance properties of the Lagrangian, e.g., that $\mathcal{L}$ is invariant under the induced action of $G$ on $TM$?  Also, would you rather have $\mathcal{L}(\lambda v) = |\lambda|\mathcal{L}(v)$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $v\in TM$?  (Without the absolute value sign, the value of the action will depend on the orientation of the curve.)

Comment: Let's say initially that absolute homogeneity is not guaranteed. I guess I'm asking what the needed invariance properties are.

Comment: I should have said $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: Are you at least going to assume that $\mathcal{L}^2:TM\to\mathbb{R}$ is nondegenerate?  Also, I suppose that you mean only to ask that the stationary curves will be of the desired form *up to reparametrization*, since, otherwise, your desired form could never hold for *all* stationary curves.

Comment: Yes, I mean only the images of the curves coincide

Comment: And yes, I would like to assume non-degeneracy. Sorry for lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer as much as it is a caution that the problem, even with the extra assumptions I was able to solicit from the OP, is not going to have a very nice answer unless one adds some further hypotheses.

To see why, just look at the case that the dimension of the homogeneous space $M$ is equal to $2$.  Even for $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $G$ is the group of Euclidean motions of the plane, there exists a huge family of Lagrangians on $TM$ such that the geodesics (up to parametrization) are the straight lines (basically two arbitrary functions of two variables worth of such Lagrangians, according to Darboux).  Since, for this $M$ and $G$, each straight line is of the form desired by the OP, that means that there are many, many solutions to the problem, even in this simple case.  (Note that most of these Lagrangians will not be invariant under $G$, even though the resulting geodesic path geometry is invariant under $G$.)

More generally, if $M=G/K$ is a surface endowed with just about any path geometry such that the (unparametrized) paths are all of the form $exp(tx)\cdot p$ for some $x\in \frak{g}$ and $p\in M$ and such that the set of paths forms a smooth surface of its own (and it is easy to construct many such examples), there will be a large family of nondegenerate Lagrangians on $TM$ whose geodesics are the curves in the path geometry.  This family will depend on two arbitrary functions of two variables, though it will not be easy to write them down explicitly.

Thus, in my opinion, the question has too many solutions, even in the $2$-dimensional case, for there to be a good answer to the OP's question.

Comment: If you take a 2-torus and your Lagrangians are smooth Finsler metrics you will only have flat metrics. For $C^1$ metrics you have a lot more, but a lot depends on the gobal character of the path geometry.

Comment: But even the *flat* smooth Finsler metrics on the $2$-torus depend on an arbitrary function because the unit circle at one point can be any smooth closed curve that is strongly convex towards the origin.  Also, the path geometry of the flat $2$-torus can't be written as $G/K$ where all the (unparametrized) geodesics are orbits of $1$-parameter subgroups of $G$, nor is the space of geodesics a smooth $2$-manifold.

Comment: Perhaps it's a matter of the topology of G and M? The plane is non compact but the torus is compact and the answers seems vacuous for the plane but interesting for the torus. I'm specifically interested in the case $SU(N+1)/U(N) \cong \mathbb{C}P^N$ all of which are compact.

Comment: @Benjamin:  Even in that case, say $N=1$, there are many different Finsler metrics on the $2$-sphere ($=\mathbb{CP}^1$) whose geodesics are the (oriented) great circles, and hence all of these are examples of the kind of Lagrangian you are hoping to classify, with $G = \mathrm{SU}(2)$ and $K= \mathrm{U}(1) = S^1$.  Even in this simple case, writing down all of these Lagrangians explicitly is not trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments, I'll have to refine my hypotheses then!

Comment: This paper contains many useful things relevant to the question: http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1495.

Comment: Note, though, that the author of that paper assumes that his Lagrangian is $G$-invariant, which you did not want to do, when I asked you about it at the beginning.  Obviously, classifying $G$-invariant Lagrangians with the desired property is a *much* simpler project than the one you originally wanted.  Also, he assumes that the Lagrangian (and not just its square) is non-degenerate, so that the geodesics have to have a group-derived parametrization as well, again, something you did not want to do.

Comment: Yes, I see that. I was thinking to follow the proofs given in the paper to try to see if G-invariance is the weakest condition for all stationary curves being of the desired form. This doesn't seem to be easily achieved.